# Should [code-golf] challenges with bonuses be tagged [code-challenge] instead?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, tags

We've had a [discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/should-bonuses-be-allowed-for-code-golf-questions) on whether or not [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges with bonuses should be allowed. This is a related, but different topic.

Currently, challenges that have non-standard objective scoring methods (a single method not covered by one of the tags [listed here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/908/45941), or a combination of standard and/or non-standard methods) fall under the category of [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge). There is one glaring exception: [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) with bonuses is still [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Should we recategorize these to fall under the [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) category?

Comment: I don't see the difference between this question and the one you linked. Despite the title the other one also asks whether code golf with bonuses should be tagged code challenge instead.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Oops, shame on me for not reading the linked question thoroughly.